# Frida android can't find out WebView instance

Tags: javascript, java, android, root, frida

I tested on some android apps that has an embedded WebView or sub-class of android.webkit.WebView, on a frida shell I can use the frida api Java.choose to find a webview instance like this code:

```
Java.perform(function() {
    Java.choose("android.webkit.WebView", {
        "onMatch": function(o) {
            try {
                console.log('object is ', o);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log("Execution failed " + e.message);
            }
        },
        "onComplete": function() {
            console.log("Execution completed")
        }
    })
}
);
```

The code successfully finds a webview instance and logs it out on app like in this apk in this repo https://github.com/agusibrahim/Android-Web-Inspector
However, on other apps I am sure that do containing a WebView once loaded in an activity like facebook app (com.facebook.katana) in its built-in browser, or the chrome android browser (com.android.chrome), the above code does not catch the "onMatch" block and go straight to the "onComplete" block. I did inspect the view hierarchy of these two apps and could surely see they contain WebView in their view hierarchy once a webpage is being showed. Please help me figure out why this happens and what other code I can try to point to the webview instance in cases like this.

I check the app's view hierarchy to make sure it contains android.webkit.WebView
I expect the frida script would find and log out a webview instance in the shell console

Comment: I do remember having read about some internal optimizations that prevent Frida sometimes to work correctly. There was also a Frida command to "unoptimized" everything. Unfortunately I wasn't able find the documentation of that command again.

Comment: Finally found it, not sure if it helps you but it is at least worth a try: `Java.performNow(function(){
    Java.deoptimizeEverything();
    // hooks
}`